# Undestand better XA Datasource

Tags: java, mysql, jpa, wildfly, datasource

I want to separate 2 table in 2 different location database... so 1 MySQL database in one datacenter and the other 1 in another.

I'm using a normal datasource in Wildfly connected to a java application using JPA. Now i want to mantain only one datasource configured in the entity manager. But i have to connect a second database and manage in a single transaction with the first one.

To do this i think i need a XA Datasource, so i have to configure in wildfly a single datasource that contain the 2 connections string that point to my 2 MySQL database and in the persistance.xml point the jta datasource to the XA datasource name? Is that correct?

Is for this case that XA datasource exist, for the managment of the transaction between 2 database in a transparency way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should configure one individual datasource for each schema.

MySQL and MariaDB are not fully XA compatible. I noticed lots of issues when using JTA inside a Wildfly server. One major issue is that MySQL and MariaDB do not support nested transactions properly, as JTA requires.

One example:

```
start transaction;
insert into user...
    start transaction;
    insert into user_details...
    commit;
insert into orders...
rollback;
```

What you would expect is that everything gets rolled back because the outer transaction was rolled back. But instead, the inserts into user and user_details tables will be committed and only the order will be rolled back.

The whole transaction management of Java EE produces strange result due to that limitation. So better don't use it at all.

I wrote an article about testing Java enterprise applications, which contains an example how to use EntityManagerFactory and EntityManager without JTA:

http://stefanfrings.de/enterprise_junit/index.html#jndi

Translation into english:

https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=de&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fstefanfrings.de%2Fenterprise_junit%2F (jump to the JNDI chapter)

Comment: Yes, but if i need a datasource for 2 different database? which can be the solution? 
Pratically i need to connect with JPA table from 2 different databasa in an unique transaction without configuring 2 datasource

Comment: It is impossible to use one datasource with multiple databases (or schemata) with JPA.

Comment: "MySQL and MariaDB are not fully XA compatible" is nonsense. As is the assertion that JTA requires nested transactions. It explicitly doesn't. JTA 1.2, section 3.1: "Support for nested transactions is not required."

Comment: Sorry but, if JPA not support this how the people implement pseudonymization? because i need to access the identification data in a database and the data in another Database manteining the transaction

Comment: In Oracle and MySQL it is possible to create virtual tables that are stored on a different DB server. Access to these tables are automatically forwarded by the DB server to the other DB server. In MySQL this feature is called "federated table". However I do not know if that feature supports transactions properly.

Comment: @Stefan this is exactly what i'm searching for, thanks a lot.